# Determine if two lines intersect

Tags: math, geometry, intersection, line-intersection

I've seen many postings here on stackoverflow, which are discussing this topic. I took a solution from stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the posting. It was to say: If two lines are intersecting, then the crossproduct produces for the left and the right side two different results. One positive and one negative. Otherwise both have the same sign. So far it is okay.
The used formula is, where AB is one line and CD another.

> dotproductleft = (B.x-A.x)*(C.y-B.y)-(B.y-A.y)*(C.x-B.x)
>
> dotproductright = (B.x-A.x)*(D.y-B.y)-(B.y-A.y)*(D.x-B.x)

If I calculate this for the following given GPS coordinates I get an intersection, in a case where no intersection is possible.

> A: x: 15.4433917 y: 47.0697272
>
> B: x: 15.4433661 y: 47.0697722
>
> C: x: 15.4434363 y: 47.0696776
>
> D: x: 15.442966  y: 47.0700098

If I draw it on Google Maps Engine, I can see that there definitely no intersection between these lines.

The results for dotproductleft: -7.372399999828474E-10 and for dotproductright: 1.1921940000328E-8

It is working for other examples very well, but here I've seen that it is not working right. But I couldn't spot any error in the formula.

[image: The points on Google Maps]

Comment: [The post you mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect), for reference.

Comment: Or is it? That seems to say something different

Comment: No its not that reference what I was looking for. But the answer from Jacob brought to an idea.

Comment: Just so you know, the dot product between AB and CD is `(B.x-A.x)*(D.x-C.x) + (B.y-A.y)*(D.y-C.y)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *lines* which contain any line segment (e.g. AB and CD) will always intersect (unless they are parallel).

You want to check if the *line segments* intersect. This is easy to do by finding the point of intersection and checking if it lies on both line segments.

So, using your example, the two lines (on which line segments AB and CD lie on) intersect at *P = (15.4434,47.0697)*. Now, if *P* lies on AB then the dot product of *PA* and *PB* is negative (since the angle between *PA* and *PB* is 180° and *cos(180°)=-1*).

If you compute the dot product of PA and PB, you will get a positive number (thus it **does not**  lie on AB). However, the dot product of PC and PD gives you a negative number (thus it lies on CD).

Thus, you can check if the line segments intersect if the aforementioned dot products (with the point of intersection) are negative.